# Android - How to set typeface to bold on clicking a list item

Tags: android, classcastexception, textview, android-view

I am trying to set a row to bold on clicking it. But it gives me a ClassCastException when I try to convert view into TextView like the following -

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
  int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)view;
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
        });
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I go about it?

EDIT:

My adapter looks like -

```
public class CountryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> names;

public CountryListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> names) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(names.get(position));

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: well, can't you see the actual runtime type of view and thus see where this classcast exception comes from? Basically if your adapter's getView method returns TextView there shouldn't be any troubles, if it returns something else - there lies the problem. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your adapter code shows the main cause of failure:

According to your adapter code the `view` you cast is the rowView, not the textView.So you should access it also that way. That's why you get `ClassCastException`.

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) {
        View rowView = view
        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your list item is a `TextView`? Usually it is a more complex structure (e.g. a `LinearLayout`). And if this is the case you need to find out the `TextView` in question within that layout using `findById()`.

Comment: Now as you updated with EDIT section it just proves the list item is not a TextView.