# Android - how to change the typeface of all other rows of a list every time a row is selected?

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I set the typeface of a row of my list to bold when I click on it. I use the following code to do that -

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
            View rowView = view;
                TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        }
        });
```

However, if I select another row, the previously selected row still stays bold. I want the typeface of that row to be changed to normal. How could I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to set typeface to bold on clicking a list item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159623/android-how-to-set-typeface-to-bold-on-clicking-a-list-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the position passed as an argument to onItemClick in a member variable of your class. Then on each onItemClick if this field is initialized with a proper value( i.e != -1) do like this

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {
            if(mPreviouslySelectedPosition != INVALID_POSITION)
            {
                final View rowView = parent.getItemAtPosition(mPreviouslySelectedPosition);
                ((TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.label1)).setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            mPreviouslySelectedPosition = position;
    }
    });
```